# Unity WheelCollider motorTorque acceleration with ps4 triggers

Tags: unity, playstation4

I'm fairly new to Unity and i'm struggling to find some answers. Every car script and wheelCollider tutorial I can find is based in the horizontal and vertical axis and that works great. But I'd like to move the car while holding a trigger and brake the car while holding another trigger (ps4 controller. Inputs are already mapped and working), but I need some help on that.

This is the part of the script that handles the acceleration:

```
 float motor = maxMotorTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
 foreach (AxleInfo axleInfo in axleInfos) {
     axleInfo.leftWheel.motorTorque  = motor;
     axleInfo.rightWheel.motorTorque = motor;
 }
```

Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction or possibly provide some example scripts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See the trigger pressing input. If it's pressing keep the value in a Boolean.

The code will be like:

```
if(pressing_trigger) //trigger values are [0-1] so pressing_trigger is true when trigger value is greater than 0 (zero).
{
//your acceleration code
}
```

Go to [xbox/ps trigger setup](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/614475/how-to-assign-ps4xb360-controller-triggers.html)